# Can I sum the gradients in each training iteration?

Tags: neural-network, gradient, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation

I need to sum the gradients in each iteration and then transfer these gradients to another process to reproduce the learned network.

The key code is like this below. Method 1:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, max_action):
        super(Actor, self).__init__()

        self.l1 = nn.Linear(state_dim, 40)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(40, 30)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(30, action_dim)

        self.max_action = max_action

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.l1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.l2(x))
        x = self.max_action * torch.tanh(self.l3(x))
        return x

def train(batches,state_dim, action_dim, max_action):
    actor = Net(state_dim, action_dim, max_action)
    critic = Net(state_dim, action_dim, max_action)

    for i in range(1000):
        ...
        #Compute critic loss
        critic_loss = F.mse_loss(current_Q, target_Q)

        # Optimize the critic
        critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
        critic_loss.backward()
        critic_optimizer.step()

        # Compute actor loss
        actor_loss = -critic(state,actor(state)).mean()

        # Optimize the actor
        actor_optimizer.zero_grad()
        actor_loss.backward()
        actor_optimizer.step()



    return net

...
net = train(batches,state_dim, action_dim, max_action)
```

Method 2:

```py
...

def train(batches,state_dim, action_dim, max_action):
    net = Net(state_dim, action_dim, max_action)
    for i in range(1000):
        ...

        # Optimize the critic
        critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
        critic_loss.backward()
        sum_grads(critic) # sum the gradient in critic

    for g,p in zip(sum_grads,net.parameters()):
        p.grad = torch.from_numpy(g)
    net_optimizer.step()

    return net

...
net = train(batches,state_dim, action_dim, max_action)
```

I hope method 1 and method two can learn the same net parameters, but it didn't. So my question is why? And how to make it work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the code, or the algorithm, something to help us helping you.

Comment: Hey, I have posted some code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to explicitly sum grads, you just have to zero_grad once, apply forward and backward but no step in a loop and call step once

```
model.zero_grad()                                   # Reset gradients tensors
for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(training_set):
    predictions = model(inputs)                     # Forward pass
    loss = loss_function(predictions, labels)       # Compute loss function
    loss = loss / accumulation_steps                # Normalize our loss (if averaged)
    loss.backward()                                 # Backward pass
    if (i+1) % accumulation_steps == 0:             # Wait for several backward steps
        optimizer.step()                            # Now we can do an optimizer step
        model.zero_grad()                           # Reset gradients tensors
```

Comment: Thanks. However, in every iteration, I have to update the network parameter(actor-critic architecture, use the updated critic to help update actor parameter). So how to deal with this situation?

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to accumulate your grads for some minibatchs and apply them together (because you get out of memory problems with large batch sizes), you can use my code. That's exactly what you are trying to do in your second method. Otherwise, your first method is correct and it works.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the example code. In the training process, firstly update the critic network and then use that network to train the actor-network. So it seems it is necessary to update parameters in each iteration.